# Upload spring-boot jar into GCE Instance using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

What is the best way copying some-spring-boot.jar into GCE Instance?

I thought this is quite a common task, but after googling found zero documentation about it.

I have already generated service account in GCP and saved all the stuff into gcp-credentials.json :

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "some project",
  "private_key_id": "someid",
  "private_key": "some key",
  "client_email": "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxdeveloper.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Here is what I'm doing after googling for hours:

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        google = {
            source = "hashicorp/google"
        }
    }
}

provider "google" {
    version = "3.5.0"
    credentials = file("gcp-credentials.json")
    project = "some project"
    zone = "us-central1-a"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
    name = "my-instance"
    machine_type = "e2-medium"
    #metadata_startup_script = file("startup.sh")

    tags = [
        "http-server",
        "https-server"]

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = "some image with jdk"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
        network = "default"
        access_config {}
    }

    provisioner "file" {
        source = "../../../target/my-jar-1.0.0.jar"
        destination = "/tmp/my-jar-1.0.0.jar"

        connection {
            type = "ssh"
            user = "root"
            private_key = file("gcp-credentials.json").private_key
            agent = "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run it says

```
[ERROR] Error: Missing required argument
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   on main.tf line 43, in resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance":
[ERROR]   43:         connection {
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] The argument "host" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested (also I have never used Terraform towards GCP), try:

```
host = self.network_interface.0.network_ip
```

Line of thought:

- the `host` indeed seems required (as per [docs for connection](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html))
- the same docs hint on the special `self` variable:

> Expressions in connection blocks cannot refer to their parent resource
> by name. Instead, they can use the special self object.
>
> The self object represents the connection's parent resource, and has
> all of that resource's attributes.

- rest is my guess how to get an IP address from a GCP instance